# Can you use character frequency to tell whether the given file is a Python program file, C program file or a text file?

Tags: python

Write a program to count frequency of characters in a given file. Can you use character frequency to tell whether the given file is a Python program file, C program file or a text file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Open Letter to Students with Homework Problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). You can't just dump your problem statement here and expect us to do it for you. It's also a good idea to take the [tour], read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

While you could spend the time sampling different python and c scripts, and there would definitely be associations, there would always be edge cases, especially if your text file happened to contain a lot of `{}`

In short: yes, probably
In long: but you wouldn't want to rely upon it